# How to create and upload a large zip file to s3 with low memory using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to download a list of s3 files and compress it into a file, but the list of files can be very large and take up a lot of memory space.

The immediate solution is to download all the files compress them and upload it to s3

```py
def upload_zip_file(event,context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    list_keys = event['list_keys']
    data_io = BytesIO()
    filename = "file.pdf"
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(data_io, 'w')

    for key in list_keys:
        s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=DATA_BUCKET_NAME, Key=key)
        body = s3_object['Body'].read()
        zf.writestr(filename,body, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    zf.close()
    s3.upload_fileobj(data_io, ZIP_BUCKET_NAME, filename)
```

With this solution when I download all the data, the total size of the zip file is stored in memory and can be larger than 1 GB. How can I upload the zip in small parts without reaching the full size?.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: How would you be filling the hard disk with your zip file? It doesn't appear you're writing it to your hard disk, but instead to a `BytesIO()` buffer

Comment: Sorry, in RAM memory

Comment: I want to upload the compressed file without filling the memory (RAM)